# Create object type with rowid attributes

Tags: oracle, object, oracle11g, ddl, rowid

I am trying to create a type with the `rowid` data type, but I am getting this error because of the type I am trying to use:

```
SQL> CREATE TYPE join_t IS OBJECT (inn  rowid,    out rowid ); 
/

Warning: Type created with compilation errors.
```

Even though I can create a table with rowid data type:

```
SQL> create table test_rowid (inn rowid,out rowid);

Table created.
```

Is it possible to create this type `join_t` above, with rowid-type attributes?

Comment: "Is it possible". No, it's not. [Restrictions on datatype](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/create_type.htm#LNPLS01375)

Answer (score 5):

No, you can't create an object type with `rowid` fields. If you looks at the actual error raised, via the `user_errors` view or with the SQL*Plus command `show errors`, you will see:

```
LINE/COL ERROR
-------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1/28     PLS-00530: Illegal type used for object type attribute: 'ROWID'.
1/39     PLS-00530: Illegal type used for object type attribute: 'ROWID'.
```

[The documenation says](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/create_type.htm#BABEHDBJ):

> **Restrictions on datatype**
>
> - You cannot impose the NOT NULL constraint on an attribute.
> - You cannot specify attributes of type ROWID, LONG, or LONG RAW.
> - You cannot specify a data type of UROWID for an ADT.
>     ...

As a workaround, you could potentially use a string type in your object, and convert the values when setting to getting the field values, via the [`rowidtochar`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions171.htm#SQLRF06101) and [`chartorowid`](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions026.htm#SQLRF00615) functions:

```
CREATE TYPE join_t IS OBJECT (inn varchar2(18), out varchar2(18) );
/

Type JOIN_T compiled

SELECT join_t(rowidtochar(rowid), rowidtochar(rowid)) FROM DUAL;

JOIN_T(ROWIDTOCHAR(ROWID),ROWIDTOCHAR(ROWID))(INN, OUT)
-------------------------------------------------------
JOIN_T('AAAAB0AABAAAAOhAAA', 'AAAAB0AABAAAAOhAAA')
```

Storing rowids in an object doesn't seem particularly useful though, as they can change.

Comment: I am doing so ... using the char type within the function ROWIDTOCHAR.
Wanted to know if I really could't make it

Comment: @Siqueira - your question didn't mention that. And no, you really can't use `rowid` as an object attribute data type, sorry.